# More than two weeks and no sign of processed application?

Tags: visas, schengen, application-status, vfs-global

I applied in London at VFS for a Schengen visa. It's been just over two weeks and there's no sign of the application. 
It's processed not in London but at the Ministry of Foreign Affairs in Netherlands.
They said that I should contact VFS for updates but VFS don't have updates.
Apparently they can keep your application for as long as they want.
I'm kind of worried and was wondering what steps I could take to get an update.

I'm wondering if my passport has been lost or misplaced.

I've applied for Schengen visas in the past and got them in less than a week.

Comment: Do you have an actual question? We don't work for VFS here so we can't track it down for you.

Comment: There's no need to be rude. I'm asking if anyone here has had a similar experience, and if so, what steps they took to perhaps get a status update. I've found information about steps that people took with a few other Schengen countries in this situation, but can't find anything about the Netherlands.

Comment: Not trying to be rude. There's literally no question-mark in the entire body of your post, and though the title has a question mark it is not an actual grammatical sentence. I had no idea what you were asking.